# How to subscription AJAX when check in checkbox in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've tested this jQuery, this code works: http://jsfiddle.net/ukduy/vyfdx8p4/,
but in my code it doesn't work:

This is my checkbox. I use "IsCheck" for control checkbox status. I used both of the 2 options.

```
<div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        @if (item.IsCheck)
        {
            @*@Html.CheckBox(item.SessionID.ToString(), item.IsCheck, new { @class = "form-check checkper", @id = item.SessionID, @name = item.SessionID })*@
            <input class="form-check-input checkper" type="checkbox" id="@item.SessionID" checked />
            <span class="form-check-sign">
                <span class="check"></span>
            </span>
        }
        else
        {
            @*@Html.CheckBox(item.SessionID.ToString(), item.IsCheck, new { @class = "form-check checkper", @id = item.SessionID, @name = item.SessionID })*@
            <input class="form-check-input checkper" type="checkbox" id="@item.SessionID" />
            <span class="form-check-sign">
                <span class="check"></span>
            </span>
        }
    </label>
</div>
```

And this is jQuery below html code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".checkper").on("change", function () {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: '/Admin/UserPermision/RemoveSession?userid=' + $('#cbbUser').val() + '&sessionid=' + $(this).val,
                    type: 'GET',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And for the controller, I have this with a point for debug. I do not know why it does not work. I think something is wrong in my jQuery code.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
      public JsonResult RemoveSession([FromUri] int userid, [FromUri] int sessionid)
      {
         List<string> temp = new List<string>();
         return Json(temp);
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a a wild guess, as you don't really tell us what exactly it is that's not working, but in this line:

```
url: '/Admin/UserPermision/RemoveSession?userid=' + $('#cbbUser').val() + '&sessionid=' + $(this).val
```

You use `$(this).val`

First of all, you need to invoke `.val()` as a method, and not a property. Secondly, `$(this).val()` in this case, would not be an integer (your expected SessionId), as you have not set an integer value for your checkbox (You've set it as the ID instead).

But you need to tell us more about what is not working. You could show us the requested URL that your ajax method calls when you click a checkbox, for instance.

Comment: In another case, with @Html.DropDownListFor, it passed on controller when I debugged.
In this case, I tried to put '/Admin/Userpermision/RemoveSession' and edit controller again, but still failed. I put 'error' in ajax, it response alert error in web browser.

Comment: Actually, I don't have request URL, because of no response when I clicked on this check box

Comment: Now It's working. I found wrong parameter in controller.